# How to fix Unable to upload file. TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'",) when trying to upload a csv file

Tags: python, csv

Why i got the error of `Unable to upload file. TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'",)` when trying to upload a .csv file in order to update the value of my model fields?

The first line of my .csv file has the sku of the products , which is CharField field in my model
The second line of my .csv file has the quantity of the products , which is DecimalField field in my model.

Here is my code:

```
def upload_massive_skus_and_quantities(request):
    #list_with_not_uploaded_skus=[]
    sum_updated=0
    sum_created=0
    total=0
    data = {}
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, "csv/upload2_csv.html", data)
    # if not GET, then proceed
    try:
        csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]
        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            messages.error(request,'File is not CSV type')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("upload_massive_skus_and_quantities"))
        #if file is too large, return
        if csv_file.multiple_chunks():
            messages.error(request,"Uploaded file is too big (%.2f MB)." % (csv_file.size/(1000*1000),))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("upload_massive_skus_and_quantities"))

        file_data = csv_file.read()    
        lines = file_data.split("\n")
        #loop over the lines and save them in db. If error , store as string and then display
        for line in lines:
            fields = line.split(";")
            sku_field=fields[0] #take the sku
            quantity_field=fields[1] #take the quantity
            fetched_product=Product.objects.get(code=sku_field)

            try:
                #update
                fetched_warehouse_product=Warehouse_Has_Products.objects.get(warehouse_id=12,warehouse_product_id=fetched_product.id) 
                fetched_warehouse_product.quantity=Decimal(quantity_field)
                fetched_warehouse_product.save()
                sum_updated+=1
                total+=1
            except:
                #create
                Warehouse_Has_Products.objects.create(warehouse_id=12,warehouse_product_id=fetched_product.id,quantity=Decimal(quantity_field)) 
                sum_created+=1
                total+=1
    except Exception as e:
        logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("Unable to upload file. "+repr(e))
        messages.error(request,"Unable to upload file. "+repr(e))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("upload_massive_skus_and_quantities"))
```

The error i think raises from the line : `file_data = csv_file.read()`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace for your error?

Comment: @dspencer Unable to upload file. TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'",)
This is the only error that i got

Comment: At the moment, you are losing the stack trace by only outputting `repr(e)`. If you `raise e` from the `except` clause, you should get more information. To be clear, I'm referring to your last `except` clause.